# How to format background color of a cell which is under a group? - SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have the following matrix:

- Design view

```
--------------------------
|  OfficeSID  | [Type]   |
--------------------------
| [OfficeSid] | [Value]  |
--------------------------
```

- Preview

```
----------------------------
| OfficeSID |   A  |   B   |
----------------------------
|    1      | 1029 |  982  |
----------------------------
|    2      |   98 |  782  |
----------------------------
|    3      |  786 |   82  |
----------------------------
|    4      |   29 |    2  |
----------------------------
```

I want to format background color of the cells i.e 2nd row, 2nd column which is a value field. It is grouped under Type field. 
The background color should be the following:

- If value < 0 red
- If value < 100 and > 0 Orange
- If value >= 100 Green

I tried using expressions but it dint work.

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty common requirement... It sounds like you're trying to set the `BackgroundColor` property at the cell level, which is correct, so there's no reason it shouldn't be working.

What expression are you using? I'd use something like:

```
=Switch(Fields!Value.Value < 0, "Red"
  , Fields!Value.Value > 0 and Fields!Value.Value < 100, "Orange"
  , Fields!Value.Value >= 100, "Green")
```

**Edit after comment:**

Hmm, not sure what's going on with your report. I put together a basic example to match your results and it's working as expected.

Put together sample dataset:

[image]

Create matrix:

[image]

Expression for *Value* Text Box `BackgroundColor` property, literally copied and pasted from the answer above:

[image]

Final results, which looks like it's working as expected:

[image]

So I'm not sure what to suggest here... About the only thing I can think of is whether you have multiple values per OfficeSID/Type combination, in which case you'd need to use an aggregate in the expression, i.e. something like:

```
=Switch(Sum(Fields!Value.Value) < 0, "Red"
  , Sum(Fields!Value.Value) > 0 and Fields!Value.Value < 100, "Orange"
  , Sum(Fields!Value.Value) >= 100, "Green")
```

But other than that I guess you could either add the exact details of the data you're using, or start a new report from the ground up in the simplest way possible. This would show if you can get the background working in a new report with no other logic in place.

Comment: Hi, ya it's a simple one. I used the expression same as you, thought it would work but to my surprise it's not changing the colors accordingly. For <0 it's changing to red n also for second condition also it's red. I don't understand the problem here :(. I tried all the ways i can but dint succeed.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, sorry. I've added an example with my original answer in action.